# Role play in laboratory experiments - literature hints?

Tags: experimental-psychology, behavior, behavioral-economics, environmental-psychology

I want to conduct a laboratory experiment with a cohort of students to assess the determinants of their willingness to adopt an environmentally friendly technology in farming. I want them to imagine they were not students but a farmer. I want to create a most realistic decision situation.
What is the name of this method/field of experimental design?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. If you want to obtain the most realistic results possible, why choose non-farmers? Students might give an idea on how students might think about environmentally friendly sources of food but surely, adoption of environmentally friendly farming techniques and technology would need to be acted on by the farmers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are totally right. Farmers do know best about this and I will run this experiment with farmers later on. The student experiments shall hold as a pre-study.